# Can I retrieve my question that was deleted?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

Recently I deleted my own question because somebody pointed out it was off-topic according to the FAQ. Is there anyway I can retrieve the question (title and body)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admins and 10K+ users can see deleted questions/answers, and I think you can see your own ones too if you know the URL for them. What was the question about and do you know which day you deleted it? We can have a look through the mod tools and see if we can find it.

Comment: I think I asked it around 24-36 hours ago. It's about financial app, can you find the URL?

Comment: @louisRhys here's your question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44655/application-or-widgets-that-monitor-both-stock-prices-and-exchange-rates Found from this page: http://android.stackexchange.com/users/136/louis-rhys?tab=questions&sort=newest